# Regular Expression Gives Core Dumped

Tags: regex, grep, cygwin, html-parsing

I am trying to parse film names from the IMDB top 250 list (from page source) which is full of html tags.
I have a regular expression, but when I run it with the grep command, after a while it gives core dumped. Command is as follows:
`grep -o -P ">[[A-Z]+\w* ([a-zA-Z]+\w* ?)*<" film.xml`.
What is the reason of this core dumped?

Comment: You've fallen victim to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: Yes, the: `[a-zA-Z]+\w*` part is like: `a+a*` - [a regex non-no](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do, but try with:

```
grep -o -P ">[A-Z]\w*( [a-zA-Z]\w*)* ?<" film.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is too greedy. This typically happens when you use `*` inside a group, which itself has a `*`. Reduce number of `*` and `+` or use their non-greedy forms: `*?` and `+?`, it will help a lot.